# Correct migrate from express to fastify with Apollo GraphQL Federation

Tags: node.js, apollo, apollo-client, fastify

I'm moving from Express to Fastify and stuck on starting server with graphql playground endpoint that should be `localhost:*/graphql`

`server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' })` is an express but googled around i needed to use `server.register(server.createHandler({ app, path: '/graphql' }))` but then i get error `root plugin has already booted`

```
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground } from 'apollo-server-core'
import { ApolloGateway } from '@apollo/gateway'
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-fastify'
import Fastify from 'fastify'

const app = Fastify()

const serviceList = [
  {
    name: 'Service One',
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/service_one/graphql',
  },
  {
    name: 'Service Two',
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/service_two/graphql',
  },
]

app.get('/', (req, reply) => {
  reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
})

const gatewayLoad = async () => {
  const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
    serviceList,
    // debug: true,
  })

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    gateway,
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground()],
    // debug: true,
  })

  await server.start()
  // Express `applyMiddleware`, how to make fastify?
  server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' })
}

gatewayLoad()

app.listen(8080, (err, address) => {
  console.info(`Server is listening on port ${address}`)
})
```

package.json

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/gateway": "2.0.0-alpha.2",
    "apollo-server": "^3.6.1",
    "apollo-server-fastify": "^3.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "dotenv": "^11.0.0",
    "fastify": "^3.25.3",
    "graphql": "16.2.0",
    "pino-http": "^6.5.0",
    "pino-pretty": "^7.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.8",
    "@types/pino": "^7.0.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.9.1",
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
```

Comment: Could you add your Fastify's code?

Comment: sorry got code mixed up, should have been fastify stuff here, edited now

Comment: you should move `app.listen()` inside the `gatewayLoad` method